# Write to file using Django?

Tags: python, html, django, web, pi

I'm trying to do what I thought was straightforward but am discovering is not. I'm hosting a webserver locally on a Raspberry Pi using Django and I want to allow the user to browse to the server, type something in a text box and then have that appended to a file sitting on the Pi.

So far, I have Django displaying a really basic HTML page, but I can't get it to execute any of the functions in my views file and I also don't know if the easiest route here is to work with a POST request and have some function set up to listen and write the contents of that?

Comment: That's essentially it, yes. Just call Python read/write operations from a Django view. If you can't get it to execute functions in your views file, you may have a problem with how your Django setup is configured.

Comment: Just so I understand... In /theory/ calling a python write operation would work from a Django view, right?

Comment: Yes. Django views are essentially Python functions like any other -- they're just executed when you make a HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to write a view that will accept the text the user types into the box and writes it to the file...

```
def my_view_to_write_to_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # put normal python open/write/close stuff here
```

If you can't seem to get this view to execute than you need to make sure you have your urls correct.